# Rails 3 HTML escaping and WYSIWYG Editor - html showing in view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

I've read http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/ and http://asciicasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3 and i'm pretty confused. I've tried the solution in asciicasts about escaping and then typing content as html_safe. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using a [WYSIWYG editor](https://github.com/joshmcarthur/rails-ckeditor) that updates a Post with Content.

```
def create
@post = Post.new(params[:post])

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
  end
end
```

end
VERY out of the box. Now, when I enter some content, i.e. "`<p>hello, world</p>`", that exact string appears in my view (I'm using a partial, fwiw).

```
<%= scrub post.content %>
```

where my application_helper.rb file has this method:

```
def scrub(content)  
 "<strong>#{h(content)}</strong>".html_safe  
end
```

when I throw in "`<script>mal</script>`", it escapes the script. Why is the HTML showing up on the view? Here's what it looks like in the view:

```
<p>hello, world &lt;script&gt;mal&lt;/script&gt;</p>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I want to allow users to do simple content formatting where the site will display rendered HTML (like this site), but keep myself safe from scripts.

Comment: oh, the bold is appearing on the view as bolded. The <p> tags are built in the wysiwyg best i can tell. maybe there's something i have to do before saving?

Comment: it appears that <strong> is being rendered in the view properly, but it is being attached in the helper. the <p> tags saved with the post in the DB are not being rendered and not being stripped. the <script> tags are being stripped and are coming from the db. <em> tags applied in the wysiwyg also are not being stripped and the resultant content is not italicized. weird, huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to look at [sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize#readme), which has three built in modes and is customizable.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting .html_safe at the end of it. I found this answer when I was looking for a solution for myself. (sorry, I realized this was an old question. but for others)

[Rails 4 WYSIWYG Bootsy not displaying formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594898/rails-4-wysiwyg-bootsy-not-displaying-formatting)