# Rails 4 WYSIWYG Bootsy not displaying formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, wysiwyg

I've just followed the install instructions at the [the bootsy gem page](https://github.com/volmer/bootsy) and it all looks good until I save and look at the post's content.

This is what the output looks like in the view:

```
<h2>Header</h2><h3>Sub head:</h3><br><img alt="Thumb 1320236280147" src="/uploads/bootsy/image/1/1320236280147.jpg">
```

It seems that none of the html formatting is being rendered as it is being escaped by quoation marks or something like that - has anyone else had this problem? I haven't seen any issues on the github page or on SO to point me in the right direction.

I haven't done anything yet apart from follow the gem install instructions but maybe I missed something or am just making a stupid mistake.

If there's anything else you want to know please just ask.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have something like this, escape html:

`<%= f.bootsy_area(:body, class: 'bg-code').html_safe %>`

Comment: Try to add `:readonly => true`
NOTE: The HTML options disabled, readonly, and multiple can all be treated as booleans. So specifying `:disabled => true` will give disabled="disabled".

Comment: <%= f.bootsy_area :body, value: @system_email.try(:content).html_safe, readonly: true , rows: 20, cols: 100, editor_options: { link: false, color: false, blockquote: false, font_styles: false, emphasis: false, lists: false, html: false, image: false} %>

Both the options are not working.

Answer (score 4):

Sergio is correct but have the .html_safe on the output rather than the input.

For example, on a post index:

```
<%= post.body.html_safe %>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use raw?

```
<%= raw(post.body) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add to `bootsy.rb`

```
config.editor_options = {
  html: true
  .....
}
```

to enable you to toggle html in the bootsy editor .